# Where do I put rails Transactions and how do I execute them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions

I have a case where I need to create like 10000 entries in a table and after some research I decided to use a transaction to do it.

My problem is I haven't found any documentation or guide that will tell me where I put a transaction or how I execute it

Comment: Pretty vague question - are you asking for an example of how to perform a transaction in Ruby on Rails ? 
here are some results I found in google - are they what you are looking for ?
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

http://vaidehijoshi.github.io/blog/2015/08/18/safer-sql-using-activerecord-transactions/

http://markdaggett.com/blog/2011/12/01/transactions-in-rails/

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness, it's been a long day. http://vaidehijoshi.github.io/blog/2015/08/18/safer-sql-using-activerecord-transactions/ seems to answer my question, I'm not certain how I missed that with my initial searches. Thank you for pointing it out to me

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved very easily:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
  ... your code ...
end
```

The code inside the block will run within a database transaction. If any error occurs during execution, all the changes will be rolled back.

Comment: So do I create a transaction file? How do I make that transaction execute?